# I want my countdown timer to be active on two specific pages, but its affecting all pages

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie developer (and new to posting on StackOverflow), so apologise in advance if I'm not using the correct terminology or have posted incorrectly.
The issue: I need my countdown timer to activate when two pages on my website are opened.  How the timer works: begins by counting down from 45 seconds to 0, then the page reloads after a delay of 4 seconds, taking the user back to the top of the page and starts again automatically. However! all other web pages are affected in that they automatically reload after the timer period of 45 seconds.
my js code:

```
/* countdown timer for quizzes, starts when page loads  */
var timeRemaining = 45;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = `${timeRemaining}<br> secs left`;
    timeRemaining -= 1;

    if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<strong>Time's up!</strong> <br> Quiz'<br> will reset in 7 secs.";
        setTimeout();
    }
}, 1000);

/* time delay before page reloads when countdown timer expires */
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload();
}, 51000); 

html code:
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Possible that this code is at all the places. like you put this in a common header file and its being called on each page ?

Comment: No, the html <div> is only on the required two pages and is not in a header

Comment: Your `<div>` is not required. It is required to display message but not to start/stop countdown.

Comment: Yes, the <div> is just meant to display the timer in html.  I just wanted to indicate that the only 'place' where the timer would appear is on the two pages with this <div>.  All functionality is in the js code

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div>` is not required. It is required to display message but not to start/stop countdown.

Best approach will be to not load this function when it is not needed but if that is not possible, a simple `if` statement to check if `#countdown` exist should solve your problem (`else` just to show that it works).

```js
/* check if element exists  */
if (document.getElementById("countdown")) {
    /* countdown timer for quizzes, starts when page loads  */
    var timeRemaining = 10;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = `${timeRemaining}<br> secs left`;
        timeRemaining -= 1;

        if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<strong>Time's up!</strong> <br> Quiz'<br> will reset in 7 secs.";
            
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.reload();
            }, 51000);
        }
    }, 1000);
} else {
  console.log('countdown element missing');
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown22"></div>
```

Comment: Umm... new problem, the page now reloads when the timer has expired, plus a further delay of 45 seconds, instead of 4 seconds.  The other pages are no longer affected, which is good.

Comment: Managed to sort the new problem out!  Thanks for your help with this, much appreciated